# Nested ID's for React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[Nested ID's for React Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrmLl.png)

I am wondering if anyone can help me with how I could discern the difference between /film/:id/:id since its nested.

Comment: You discern them be giving them different identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an antipattern

It would get overridden

The useParams hook will try to match the keys that you have written in this case id with the value

so in this case it would get overridden, and in useParams, you will only get one id on it. which is the one that comes later.

So you rather use appropriate names

use :userId/:applicationId for example. when there are multiple ids, it is recommended to use appropriate naming conventions.